# SQL Server: how to set return format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, culture

Question: The new SQL Server 2008 database returns me values formatted English (date/float).

Is there a way I can set the return format ?

For example temporarely switching the database language?

Or just set the language for the current query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOL: Specifies the language environment for the session. The session language determines the datetime formats and system messages.

```
DECLARE @Today DATETIME
    SET @Today = '12/5/2007'

    SET LANGUAGE Italian
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @Today) AS 'Month Name'

    SET LANGUAGE us_english
    SELECT DATENAME(month, @Today) AS 'Month Name' 
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot switch the language in SQL Server for just a single statement or specify a different language for a select.

What you need to do is:

- either convert `DATETIME` to string using an appropriate "style" value in your `CONVERT` statement (see the [MSDN docs on CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) for details)
- have a batch to switch to the language needed, execute your statement, and then switch back
- don't do the switching on the SQL Server side, but in your application